# Twilio device status offline

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, twilio

I am developing a hybrid app using ionic + phonegap. I have already used iOS sdk and all works perfectly.

However when I use Android SDK the device status always returns Offline.
For what I have read, offline status is when capability token has expired or is invalid. This is the code I am using to generate capability token:

```
        var capability = new TwilioCapability(accountSid, authToken);
        capability.AllowClientOutgoing(apiSID);

        string token = capability.GenerateToken();
```

However, as I have remarked, the same code is used for iOS and works perfectly.

Any suggestions?
Do I have to configure AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<activity     android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.twilioclient.IncomingConnectionActivit y" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
<service android:exported="false"   android:name="com.twilio.client.TwilioClientService" />
```

Android Manifest has only this references to Twilio. Do I have to make available some other feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Megan from Twilio here.

From some similar interactions with our support team it seems like the best place to start would be firing up [the quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/make-outgoing-call).

And adding in external dependencies later.